# Solve a congruence linear equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Solve the following congruence:

$19x\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;36)$

My work:

I found an inverse of $19$ and $36$ which is $9$.

$9\cdot 19x\equiv 9\cdot 1\;(\text{mod}\;36)$
$171x\equiv 9\;(\text{mod}\;36)$
$9x\equiv 9\;(\text{mod}\; 36)$

$x\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;4)$ is my final answer...

Is it correct?

Comment: You made a mistake, $9\cdot 19 = 171 = 4\cdot 36 + 27$.

Comment: The inverse of $19$ modulo $36$ is _not_ $9$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method** $1:$

We need $x\equiv19^{-1}\pmod{36}$

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)  $\lambda(36)=$lcm$(6,2)=6\implies a^6\equiv1\pmod{36}$ if $(a,6)=1$
$\implies$ord$_{36}(a)$ must divide $6$

$19^1\equiv19\pmod{36},19^2=361\equiv1\pmod{36}\implies 19\equiv19^{-1}\pmod{36}$

---

**Method** $2:$

Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence), expressing as [Continued Fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Basic_formulae),

$$\frac{36}{19}=1+\frac{17}{19}=1+\frac1{\frac{19}{17}}=1+\frac1{1+\frac2{17}}=1+\frac1{1+\frac1{\frac{17}2}}=1+\frac1{1+\frac1{8+\frac12}}$$

The previous convergent of $\displaystyle\frac{36}{19}$ is $\displaystyle1+\frac1{1+\frac18}=\frac{17}9$

$\displaystyle\implies 36\cdot9-19\cdot17=1\implies-17\cdot19\equiv1\pmod{36}\implies 19^{-1}\equiv-17\equiv19$

Alternatively observe that the next  convergent of $\displaystyle\frac{36}{19}$ is $\displaystyle1+\frac1{1+\frac1{8+\frac11}}=\frac{19}{10}$

$\displaystyle\implies 36\cdot10-19\cdot19=-1\implies-19\cdot19\equiv-1\pmod{36}\implies 19^{-1}\equiv19$

---

**Method** $3:$

We have  $19x\equiv1\pmod{36}\ \ \ \ (1)$

As $36=9\cdot4$ with $(9,4)=1$

$\ \ \ \ (1)\implies 19x\equiv1\pmod9\implies x\equiv1\pmod 9$

$\ \ \ \ (1)\implies 19x\equiv1\pmod4\implies -x\equiv1\pmod 4\implies x\equiv-1\pmod 4$

Using well-known  [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html), we can show $x\equiv19\pmod{36}$

Answer (score 2):

We have that $19^2 = 361 = 36 \times 10 +1 \implies 19^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{36}$. Hence, $$x \equiv 19 \pmod{36}$$

Comment: Why did you square 19?

Comment: therexists: 19 is its own multiplicative inverse, as user17762 has shown. $19\cdot 19 = 361 \equiv 1 \pmod {36} \iff 19^2x \equiv 1\cdot x \equiv 19\cdot 1 \pmod {36}$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, perhaps less "guessing":

$$19=3\pmod 4\;\;,\;\;19=1\pmod 9$$

$$3^{-1}=3\pmod 4\;\;,\;\;1^{-1}=1\pmod 9$$

thus

$$x=19^{-1}\pmod{36=4\cdot9}\iff x=1\pmod 4\;\;\wedge\;\;x=1\pmod9\iff$$

$$\iff x=3\pmod 4\;\;\wedge\;\;x=1\pmod 9\implies x=19\pmod{36}$$

For the last step you can use The Chinese Remainder Theorem, say (though here it is overkill)