# What are the integral solutions of $239x-111y=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What are the integral solutions of $239x-111y=1$

**My Try:**

$239x-111y=1$

$239x\equiv(1$ mod $111)$

$17x\equiv(13$ mod $111)$

$17(13x)\equiv(13$ mod $111)$

$x\equiv(98$ mod $11)$

So, $x=98$

**Is my above attempt correct? Are there any better ways to solve this?**

Comment: The standard solution technique is the extended Euclidean algorithm, and there are plenty  of other solutions beyond $(98, 211)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499939/solve-a-congruence-linear-equation

Comment: The standard way to write it is $239x\equiv 1\mod 111$ or $230x\equiv 1\pmod {111}.$ That is, 239x\equiv 1 \mod 111 or 239x \equiv 1 \pmod {111}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did find a solution, but the part you're missing is that there are infinitely many such solutions.  This is a linear Diophantine equation of two variables, and there's some good information [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation) about this.  The most important part is:

> $$ax+by= c,\quad \text{(all integers)}$$
>   [The above equation] has a solution (where $x$ and $y$ are integers) if and only if $c$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Moreover, if $(x, y)$ is a solution, then the other solutions have the form $(x + kv, y − ku)$, where $k$ is an arbitrary integer, and $u$ and $v$ are the quotients of $a$ and $b$ (respectively) by the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

So, given a single solution, you can find all other solutions to the equation.  The usual approach is to use Euclid's algorithm to find $x$ and $y$ such that $\gcd(a, b) = a\cdot x + b\cdot y$, then scale appropriately (i.e. multiply the whole equation by $\frac{c}{\gcd(a, b)}$.

However, you've already found a solution, so let's skip that part.  Once you have a single solution $(x_0, y_0)$, you need to describe the solution set.  This is:

\begin{equation}
\left\{\left(x_0 + \frac{bn}{d}, y_0 + \frac{an}{d}\right) : n \in \mathbb{Z}, d = \gcd(a, b)\right\}
\end{equation}

For your case, $a$ and $b$ are coprime, so $d=1$.

Comment: To the proposer: Suppose $ab\ne 0$ and $ \gcd( a,b)=1$ and $ax+by=1.$....(I).  Clearly $a(x+nb)+b(y-na)=1$ for any $n\in \Bbb Z.$ ...(II). If $ax'+by'=1$ then $0=(x+by)-(x'+by')=a(x-x')+b(y-y')$.  So $a|b(y-y')$ and $b|a(x-x'),$ and since $\gcd (a,b)=1,$ this implies $a|(y-y')$ and $b|(x-x').$ So let $y'=y+ma$ and $x'=x+nb.$ So $0=a(x-x')+b(y-y')=anb+bma,$  so $m=-n$....  Hence $ \{(x+nb,y-na): n\in \Bbb Z\}=\{(x',y'): ax'+by'=1\}$  .

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above, but names some important ideas.

The GCD of any two integers can be expressed as a linear combination if those integers, and that in infinite ways.

239 and 111 are relatively prime. The [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm?wprov=sfla1)  can be used to find those infinite solutions.