# Is it possible to have $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 1$ for $a$, $b$, $c$ being coprime integers?

Tags: integers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares, maximal-and-prime-ideals

As stated above. I'm working on a possible proof. It appears that $$(b+1)(b-1)=(c+a)(c-a)$$ That's where I'm stuck. Any help please? A clear, simple proof desired, thanks!

Comment: Coprime, or pairwise coprime? e.g. does (5,5,7) count as coprime? (it's coprime, but not pairwise coprime)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, it counts.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised no one has given the trivial example $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$7^2+11^2=13^2+1$
They all have to be odd, otherwise two are even and not coprime.
Look for values $c^2+1$ for which $(c^2+1)/2$ is composite.  There will always be another $a^2+b^2=c^2+1$

Comment: It's just $(a,b,c)=1$. It is not given they are pairwise coprime (see op comments).

Comment: If $(a,b,c)\neq1$ then there is no solution.

Comment: I don't understand. If (a,b,c) does not equal one and therefore has no solution, then why did you give 7, 11, and 13? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: $7,11$ and $13$ have no common factor, so $(7,11,13)=1$, and it is a solution.  But if $a$, $b$ and $c$ have a common factor $d>1$, then so does $a^2+b^2-c^2$.  But $a^2+b^2-c^2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Every number whose prime divisors are of the form $4k+1$ can be written as the sum of two coprime squares. For sure, if we take $c=2^m$, every prime divisor $p$ of $c^2+1=4^m+1$ is of the form $4k+1$, because
$$ 4^m+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
implies:
$$ -1\equiv (2^m)^2,\pmod{p}$$
hence $-1$ is a square $\pmod{p}$. Moreover, if $4^m+1$ is not a prime, it can be written as a sum of two coprime squares in at least three different squares. So we have a solution for every $c=8^n$, for instance:
$$ 4^2+7^2 = 8^2+1, $$
$$ 31^2+56^2 = 64^2+1, $$
$$ \ldots $$

Comment: Is the converse true? i.e. the sum of two coprime squares must equal 4k + 1?

Comment: @HyperLuminal: No. $3^2+5^2 = 34\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity),

$$(ab+cd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(ab-cd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$$

Set $ad-bc=\pm1\implies (ad,bc)=1\implies(a,b)=(a,c)=(c,d)=(b,d)=1$

Choose arbitrary $a,b$ such that $(a,b)=1;$  then use the method described in my answer here: [Solving a Linear Congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence)  to determine $c,d$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here.  One can easily check with example like   $$a=26,b=21\implies d=4,c=5$$