# Solve for x: $5x=1 \bmod 12$

Tags: number-theory

Solve for $x$: $5x =1 \bmod12$

By hit and trial i see that $x=5$ satisfies the above. But what is the procedure for doind this

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @Nitin To find the G.C.D..yes

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence

Comment: So you know there exist integers $a,b$ such that $5a + 12b = 1$. What happens under mod 12?

Comment: In principle try to multiply mod $12$ by all numbers  up to $11$.  But anything divisible by $2$ or $3$ can't work, so don't bother with them. Then the first thing you really try works.

Comment: @Nitin $5a=1modn$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is $x = 5^{-1} \pmod {12}$. Basically you want to calculate the modular inverse of $5 \pmod {12}$, which is represented as $5^{-1} \pmod{12}$. You can use the Extended Euclidean algorithm for that. But for small modulos, it's easier to just do trial and error. You want the unique number (modulo $12$) that when multiplied by $5$ will give you a result that is $1$ modulo $12$. You only have to test numbers in the range $1$ to $11$.

You can quite easily see that $(5)(5) = 25 \equiv 1 \pmod {12}$. So $5^{-1} \equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ and the solution is $x \equiv 5 \pmod{12}$.

Comment: I agree that trial and error is the right way to do this, but it seems more efficient to test numbers of the form $12n+1$ until you find one divisible by $5$.  (Efficient not only because in this example $n=2$ already works but mainly because I find it easier to mentally test divisibility by $5$ than by $12$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, this is true. In fact, I think I exploited this method somewhere on another question on this site, but I can't seem to find it. May have been a comment in response to someone else.