# Solving a congruence with Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm

I need help solving a congruence with the help of Chinese Remainder Theorem. I am not sure how I could get 3 congruences out of one. For solving congruences I use Euclid's algorithm. Here's an example:
\begin{align*}
  19x &\equiv 7 \mod 374 \\
\end{align*}

Any tips would be massively appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you insist on using CRT then it's much easier to use $2$ (vs. $3)$ congruences - see my answer. But generally it is easier to use the extended Euclidean algorithm or Gauss's algorithm to compute such fractions, e.g. [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2052105/242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $374=2\times11\times17$, all you have to do is to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}19x\equiv7\mod2(\iff x\equiv1\mod2)\\19x\equiv7\mod11(\iff8x\equiv7\mod11)\\19x\equiv7\mod17(\iff2x\equiv7\mod17).\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: So you basically just guess the new mods? Is there any formula or recipe to guess them faster?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem approach actually leads you to do more work than directly applying Euclid's algorithm in this simple case, because you now need to solve 3 congruence and apply Euclid/Bezout twice (on the moduli $2,11,17$, although you can avoid doing the 2 by inspection instead of via Bezout) to match them up.

- If you can just apply Euclid directly:
  \begin{align*}
  374-19\times 19&=13\\
  19-13&=6\\
  13-2\times 6&=1
  \end{align*}
  and so running it backwards gives $3\times 374-59\times 19 = 1$.  Hence multiplying your given equation by $-59$ gives $x\equiv -59\times 7\pmod{374}$.
- On the other hand, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, you need to solve
  $$
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  19 x&\equiv 7\pmod{2}\\
  19 x&\equiv 7\pmod{11}\\
  19 x&\equiv 7\pmod{17}\\
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
  $$
  giving (steps omitted here)
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  x&\equiv 1\pmod 2\\
  x&\equiv 5\pmod{11}\\
  x&\equiv 12\pmod{17}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  and now you need to apply Euclid to $11,17$ and run backwards, giving
  $$
  2\times 17-3\times 11=1
  $$
  so $x\equiv 5\times (2\times 17)+12\times(-3\times 11)\pmod{187}$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$, so
  $$
  x\equiv 5\times 2\times 17+12\times(-3)\times 11+187\pmod{374}.
  $$

Comment: It's easier to use *two* congruences, e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use $2$ (vs. $3)$ congruences, i.e. $\ 374 = (2\cdot 11)\, 17 = 22\cdot 17\ $ so

$\!\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{22}\!:\,\  \overbrace{{-}3x \equiv -15^{\phantom{.}}}^{\Large\ 19x\ \ \equiv\ \ 7_{\phantom{I}}}\! \iff x\, \equiv\, \color{#0a0}5$

$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{17}\!:\  \ \ \ \ 2x \equiv -10\iff  x \equiv -5 \equiv \color{#0a0}{5+22}\,\color{#c00}k \equiv 5\!+\!5k\!\iff\! 5k \equiv-10\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{k \equiv -2}$

so substituting for $\,\color{#c00}k\,$ we obtain that: $\,\ x = 5 + 22(\color{#c00}{-2\!+\!17}n)\equiv \bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{-39\equiv 335 \pmod{\!374}}$

---

**Alternatively** applying $ $ [Gauss's algorithm and Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)  we easily compute

$\bmod 374\!:\,\   \dfrac{7}{19}  \equiv \dfrac{19\cdot 7\ \ }{19\cdot 19}\equiv \dfrac{ 133}{-13} \equiv \dfrac{\color{#90f}{133+374}}{-13}\equiv -39,\ $ by $\bmod 13\!:\,\ \color{#90f}{133}\equiv 3\equiv \color{#90f}{-374}$