# Use Fermat's Little Theorem to solve the equation $x^{13} \equiv 2\;(\mod\ 23)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have to use Fermat's Little Theorem to solve the equation
$$x^{13} \equiv 2\;(\mod\ 23)$$
But I have no idea how to do so.
I understand that $2^{23} \equiv 2\;(\mod\ 23)$.
But I don't know how to solve what the question is asking.

Comment: "Fermat's Last Theorem" is probably a typo, I don't see where that comes in! You meant the little theorem, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem says that if $x$ is relatively prime to $23$, then $x^{22}\equiv1\pmod{23}$.

Moreover, $$13\times17=221=22\times10+1.$$
So if
$$x^{13}\equiv2\pmod{23},$$
then
$$(x^{13})^{17}\equiv x^{22\times10+1}\equiv x^{1}\equiv2^{17}\pmod{23}.$$
Now $$\begin{align}2^2&\equiv4\\2^4&\equiv16\\2^8&\equiv256\equiv3\\
2^{16}&\equiv9\end{align}.$$
So $2^{17}\equiv18\pmod{23}$. As a consequence, we find that $18$ is a solution to $x^{13}\equiv2\pmod{23}$.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

⇒ $x^n=2+23k$

This equation can have numerous solutions; for example (k=1, n=2, x=5) or ( k=13, n=2, x=18)  which satisfies following congruence:

$x^2≡2 \mod 23$

If (x, 23)=1 then:

$x^{22}=(x^{11})^2 ≡ 1 \mod 23 $,⇒ $x^{11}≡ 1 \mod 23$

⇒ $x^{11}\times x^2=x^{13}≡2 \mod 23$

For example a set of solutions  for congruence $a^n ≡ 2 \mod 23$is:

$5^2, 5^{13}, 5^{13+11}=5^{24}, 5^{35}, . . .$

Another set of solution is:

$18^2, 18^{13}, 18^{24}, 18^{35}, . . .$

so for your question x=5 and x=18 and generally all number which their squares have remainder 2 when divided by 23 are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If curious you may like using [discrete log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm): 
$$x^{a} \equiv b\pmod{p} \Rightarrow a\log_rx\equiv \log_rb\pmod{p} \Rightarrow x\equiv r^{\frac{\log_rb}{a}}\pmod{p}$$

Sadly this works only when $p$ is prime.

Answer (score -1):

Let us find $a,b$ such that $13a+22b=1,$

By Observation $b=3, a=-5$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem,

$$x=x^{22(3)-5(13)}=(x^{22})^3(x^{13})^{-5}\equiv1^3\cdot2^{-5}\pmod{23}$$

Let us find $c,d$ such that $-32c+23d=1\implies c\equiv32^{-1}\pmod{23}$

Use my method from  [Solving a Linear Congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence)

Or using Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{-5}\equiv2^{17}\pmod{23}$