# How can I find inverse of something in modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this problem:  $16x ≡ 22 \quad(\text{mod} 35)$

Now I think I have to find the inverse of that. How can I?

I thought it will be $\quad x_0 = 16^{(24-1)} *22 \quad (\text{mod} 35) \quad$ but I think it is not the answer. Can someone please help me how to find it and how to make it step by step?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence/407482

Comment: Literally the same question [How can I calculate this congruence? 16x ≡ 22 (mod 35)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659535/how-can-i-calculate-this-congruence-16x-%e2%89%a1-22-mod-35)

Comment: Please don't repost your old questions.

Comment: I added some dupe links which give many methods for computing modular inverses.

Comment: $\bmod 35\!:\,\ x\equiv \dfrac{22}{16}\equiv \dfrac{44}{32}\equiv \dfrac{9}{-3}\equiv -3\,$ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$$x\equiv16^{-1}22\equiv2^{-4}22\pmod{35}$$

Now using  [Carmichael Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\lambda(35)=12,$ $$2^{-4}\equiv2^8\equiv11\pmod{35}$$

Alternatively,

As $16x\equiv1\pmod5\iff x\equiv1\pmod5$

and  $16x\equiv1\pmod7\iff 2x\equiv1\iff x\equiv2^{-1}\equiv4\pmod7$

Now apply [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)