# 5 is primitive root on modulo 47 then solve the $x^{20} \equiv21(mod47)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have tried to look powers of 5 in modulo 47 but It seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $5^3\equiv31\equiv-16,5^6\equiv(-16)^2\equiv21\pmod{47}$

Take discrete logarithm,

$20\cdot$ind$_5x\equiv$ind$_5{21}\pmod{46}\equiv6\equiv6-46$

ind$_5x\equiv-2\pmod{\dfrac{46}{(46,20)}}\implies x\equiv5^{23k-2}\pmod{47}$

Please use [Solving a Linear Congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence/407482) to find $5^{-2}\pmod{47}$

Comment: Since $\gcd(20,46)=2$, there are two solutions. They are $15$ and $32$.

Comment: @lhf, You are correct, Rectified.